# Install libreoffice in custom directory and setup

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 (minimal install). I have my /home directory on a different (bigger) partition. I would like to install Libreoffice in a custom directory in /home. I followed [this](https://blog.simos.info/how-to-install-libreoffice-in-a-directory-in-linux/) guide and have all the files in

```
~/kubuntu_apps/libreoffice6.0
```

and am able to launch libreoffice from the command line. However, it doesn't show up on the menu search and I'm not able to launch office files from the file manager. This is a bit of a hassle especially for my spouse.

How can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe it is interesting for other people to know why you would not use the standard installation path. Installing repository programs in custome locations is very unusual in Linux. When you are doing this for a certain reason one could learn something from that, perhaps.

Comment: I thought I already did? Its because my root partition is pretty small and I have a separate home partition where I would like to keep non-essential apps.

Comment: With that information it gets clear now thanks. Personally I prepare for standard office type use 10-15GB partitions for the full installation and its working fine for years. I try to keep only data in home.  Why not test-install Libreoffice on you root partition and see if the problem is still there. If no maybe the quickest fix is shuffle some space from your home to root partition.